# Extract the information from Data Flow Analysis (design time) in IBM DataStage or is there any tool which mimics it using export of a job?

Tags: python, datastage

while doing Data Flow Analysis (design time) on a field/column in DataStage jobs it becoming difficult to extract each and every data manually from a job which is very time taking and confusing

so, searching for any other alternative ways to get the data into excel or any other forms directly without manually typing seeing the output of Data Flow Analysis (design time) on a job

I want the manipulation done on a field / column , where it's originating from, to what names it has been changed and all that information which can be extracted using the Data Flow Analysis (design time).

thanks in advance